# Conway's Game of life logic error in the function

Tags: c, logic

The code is to do conway's game of life, read points in a file and it can print properly, when do once the rule, it only print me the board. If i delete the rule part, it gives me the right number of nb and locations.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int l, w, i, n, a, x, y;
char b[80][80], ip[10];
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{  

   n=argc;/*check the number of elements in argv*/
   if (n!=5){
      fprintf(stderr, "ENTERED ELEMENTS IS WRONG\n");
      exit (0);
   }

   w=atoi(argv[2]);/*read from a file*/
   l=atoi(argv[3]);

   FILE* f;
   f = fopen(argv[1],"r");
   if (f == NULL){/*print ERROR when file the is null*/
      fprintf(stderr, "ERROR READING FILE\n");
      exit (0);
   }

   for (x = 0; x < l; x++){/*all points are 0*/
       for(y = 0; y < w; y++){
          b[x][y] = 0;
        }
   }
   fscanf(f, "%d", &a);/*get the number of points*/
   for (i=0; i<a; i++){
       fscanf(f, "%d %d", &x, &y);
       b[x][y] = 1;/*the points that mentioned are 1*/
   }

   printf("*");/*To print the first line of the board*/
   for (i=0; i< w; i++){
       printf("-");
     }
   printf("*\n");

   for (x=0; x<l; x++){
        printf("|");
        for (y=0; y<w; y++){
            if (b[x][y]==1){
            printf("X");/*frint all the ponints, 0 is ' ', 1 is 'X'*/
            }
            else {
            printf(" ");
            }
        }
        printf("|\n");
     }

   printf("*");/*To print the last line of the board*/
   for (i=0; i< w; i++){
       printf("-");
     }
   printf("*\n\n");
/*the end of printing the first graph*/

   fgets(ip,10,stdin);
   while (ip!= NULL){
      generate();
      fgets(ip,10,stdin);
   }
}

void generate(void){
   int nb;
/*4 rules*/
   for (x = 1; x < l-1; x++){
       for(y = 1; y < w-1; y++){
         nb = b[x-1][y-1]
             +b[x-1][y]
             +b[x-1][y+1]
             +b[x][y-1]
             +b[x][y+1]
             +b[x+1][y-1]
             +b[x+1][y]
             +b[x+1][y+1];
         if (b[x][y]==1){
            if (nb<2||nb>3){
               b[x][y]=0;
            }else {
                b[x][y]=1;
            }
         }
         if (b[x][y]==0){
            if (nb==3){
               b[x][y]=1;
            }
         }
       }
   }

/*To print the board  same as printing the graph in main function*/
   printf("*");
   for (i=0; i< w; i++){
       printf("-");
     }
   printf("*\n");

   for (x=0; x<l; x++){
        printf("|");
        for (y=0; y<w; y++){
            if (b[x][y]==1){
            printf("X");
            }
            else {
            printf(" ");
            }
        }
        printf("|\n");
     }

   printf("*");
   for (i=0; i< w; i++){
       printf("-");
     }
   printf("*\n\n");
}
```

Comment: You are calling `generate()` without a prototype and it's declared forward

Comment: @KeineLust This shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @DYZ are you sure?

Comment: This should really be broken up into functions so it can be properly unit tested. Have you ensured neighbors are being counted correctly?

Comment: I'm not sure how to fix it. is it like to give the function a output value b[][]?

Comment: @KeineLust In this case - absolutely sure.

Comment: You only have one board. You need to calculate all of the next board before you change the current board. The best way to do that, it to swap pointers to the two boards, rather than copying the data.

Comment: @Carcigenicate i'm sure it's giving me the right coordinates and nb value

Comment: @WeatherVane do you mean set up a new 2D array like b[][], and give the new values there?

Comment: No, have two boards, all of the time. You calculate the next board from the current one. Then you flip the (pointers to the) boards.

Comment: @DYZ you mean in this case because is declared as returning nothing and` without parameters? `void generate(void)`?

Comment: You overwrite the current board with the new configuration, which distorts the further rule calculations.

Comment: @KeineLust Yes.

Comment: @DYZ I see, you are right!

Comment: @DYZ i'm still not clear how to fix it. could you plz should me where is the problem?

Comment: You need to calculate the *whole* of the next generation before you change the current state. The simplest way to do that at first is to `memcpy` then next gen to the current gen. A more sophisticated and faster approach is to swap pointers to the pair of boards, instead of copying the data.

Comment: @Savitor If you change the same board that you're trying to read, it messes up alive counts, since the new cells are effecting the old generation. You need to create a new board every time you start a new generation, or swap between 2 boards each generation.

Comment: this line: `fprintf(stderr, "ERROR READING FILE\n");` is missing the display of why the OS thinks the call to `fopen()` failed.  Suggest using: `perror("fopen for file to read failed");`  As this will both output a usable error message AND output the reason the OS thinks the call to `fopen()` failed, all to `stderr`

Comment: the posted code is missing the prototype statement (before the `main()` function) for the `generate()` function.

Comment: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis (I.E. 10, 80)  Suggest use a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, the use those meaningful names throughout the code\

Comment: regarding the code block beginning with: `for (x = 0; x < l; x++){/*all points are 0*/`  What happens if `argv[2]` or `argv[3]` is greater than 80?  The code should be checking the limits of the buffer `b[][]` against those `argv[]` values to assure that the buffer is not overrun.  Note: such overrun results in undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: regarding this code block: `if (f == NULL){/*print ERROR when file the is null*/
      fprintf(stderr, "ERROR READING FILE\n");
      exit (0);`  Returning 0 from `main()` indicates SUCCESS.  but the code has actually failed.  Should return 1 or better: EXIT_FAILURE (where `EXIT_FAILURE` is defined in `stdlib.h`

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions (like `fscanf()`), always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'. unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level.  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.  3) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent)

Comment: variable names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both) variable names likes b[][], l, w, i, n, a, x, y, ip are meaningless, even in the current context.

Comment: when the command line argument count is not a valid value, then the code should output a `USAGE` statement, similar to: `fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s fileName width length arg4\n", argv[0]);`  So the user is told what they should be entering.  Note the `arg4` is never used in the posted code,  so perhaps this line: `if( n!=5)` should actually be: `if( argc != 4)`

Comment: Since the initial points on the board are being set from a file.  It would be MUCH better if that file also contained the max rows and max columns values (perhaps as the first line in the file)  So that can be assured that the 'points' are within the bounds of the board sizing rather than using some command line parameters.  As those command line parameters are (in general) unrelated to the 'points' contained in the file

Comment: strongly suggest using two board images, one to be the source (and initial display) there after update the alternate image, then display the alternate image, etc.

Comment: in function: `generate()`, why this code block: `            else
            {
                b[x][y]=1;
            }` when the value in `b[x][y]` is already 1?

Comment: the function: `generate()` is trying to 'update inplace' which will not work.  It will not work because the original values in `b[][]` are needed for each successive `b[x][y]` to be updated.  I.E. use an alternate board to receive the updates,  Then when all the updates in this pass are completed, copy the updated board to the original board, then display the original board again.   Since the board is being displayed in multiple places, strongly suggest separating a function out that performs the display and have each place that wants to display the board, call that function

Comment: these two lines: `fgets(ip,10,stdin);
   while ( ip != NULL )` will never work as the address of `ip` never changes.  Strongly suggest re-writing that code block as: `while( fgets( ip, 10, stdin) ) { generate(); }`  However, even that will not cause the `while()` loop to exit unless the user enters EOF (<ctrl-z> or <ctrl-d> depending on the OS)

Comment: regarding int b[80][80] that would be better defined by 1) `int rows = atoi( argv[2]; int columns = atoi( argv[3] ); int b[ rows+2 ][ columns ];` I.E. using the VLA (variable length array) feature of C to properly define the size of the data board `b`

Comment: in the function: `generate()`, the 0 row or the `l` row could have effects on the life cells in that row.  Similarly the 0 column or the 'w' column could have effects on the life cells in that column.  The posted code does not handle those instances.

Answer (score 0):

You need two boards: the current one and the future (next) one: `char b[80][80], next[80][80]`. When you evaluate the rules, take the data from the current board (`b`), but record the results into the future board (`next[..][..]=...`). **After** you iterate through all cells, copy the content of the future board into the current board with `bcopy()` or in a nested loop.